# Problem with longtblr layout at page breaks when using SetCell to span rows

Tags: tabularray, longtblr

I have a problem with a `longtblr` based table where the intermediate footers cover part of the row before the page breaks.

Given the following example:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
\section{My Section}
\begin{longtblr}[
  caption = {My Long Table},
  label = {tbl:my-long-table},
  ]{
    colspec = {X[2]X[5]},
    width = \linewidth,
    rowhead = 1,
    rowfoot = 1,
    row{even} = {azure9},
    row{1,Z} = {c,font=\sffamily\bfseries,bg=azure5,fg=white},
    hlines = {azure5,solid,0.4pt},
    vlines = {azure5,solid,0.4pt}
  }
  Column 1 & Column 2 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} Row-0 & Row-0 \\
  &  Row-0 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c,bg=white} Row-1 & Row-1 \\
  &  Row-1 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} Row-2 & Row-2 \\
  &  Row-2 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c,bg=white} Row-3 & Row-3 \\
  &  Row-3 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} Row-4 & Row-4 \\
  &  Row-4 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c,bg=white} Row-5 & Row-5 \\
  &  Row-5 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} Row-6 & Row-6 \\
  &  Row-6 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c,bg=white} Row-7 & Row-7 \\
  &  Row-7 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} Row-8 & Row-8 \\
  &  Row-8 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c,bg=white} Row-9 & Row-9 \\
  &  Row-9 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} Row-10 & Row-10 \\
  &  Row-10 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c,bg=white} Row-11 & Row-11 \\
  &  Row-11 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} Row-12 & Row-12 \\
  &  Row-12 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c,bg=white} Row-13 & Row-13 \\
  &  Row-13 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} Row-14 & Row-14 \\
  &  Row-14 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c,bg=white} Row-15 & Row-15 \\
  &  Row-15 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} Row-16 & Row-16 \\
  &  Row-16 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c,bg=white} Row-17 & Row-17 \\
  &  Row-17 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} Row-18 & Row-18 \\
  &  Row-18 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c,bg=white} Row-19 & Row-19 \\
  &  Row-19 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} Row-20 & Row-20 \\
  &  Row-20 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c,bg=white} Row-21 & Row-21 \\
  &  Row-21 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} Row-22 & Row-22 \\
  &  Row-22 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c,bg=white} Row-23 & Row-23 \\
  &  Row-23 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} Row-24 & Row-24 \\
  &  Row-24 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c,bg=white} Row-25 & Row-25 \\
  &  Row-25 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} Row-26 & Row-26 \\
  &  Row-26 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c,bg=white} Row-27 & Row-27 \\
  &  Row-27 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} Row-28 & Row-28 \\
  &  Row-28 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c,bg=white} Row-29 & Row-29 \\
  &  Row-29 \\
  \SetCell[r=2]{c} Row-30 & Row-30 \\
  &  Row-30 \\
  Column 1 & Column 2 \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

I get the following output:

[image]

The intermediate footer covers row 27 partially. I am guessing this is due to using the multirow command since I do not see this behavior with a simpler `longtblr` based table.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: There is workaround to manually add `\pagebreak` after row 26.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `\\*` on each row that should be kept together with the next one. In this way LaTeX can still decide where to put the page break, in contrast to the use of `\pagebreak`.

```
  \SetCell[r=2]{c,bg=white} Row-27 & Row-27 \\*
  &  Row-27 \\
```

[image]

[image]